# How to make two div slightly tilt using transform:skew

Tags: html, css

I want a structure like this :

[image]

But i'm getting this using my html and css codes :

[image]

Here is my HTML CODE which i'm using :

```
<section>
    <div class="row footer-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="copyright">
        <p class="text-center copy-text">2018</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="copyright">
            <p class="text-center copy-text">2017</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my CSS Code which i'm using :

```
.footer-bottom:before{background-color: #000; position:absolute; top:-50px; 
left:0px; content:""; width:100%;
min-height: 80px;
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Safari */
transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Standard syntax */}

.footer-bottom { position:relative; margin-top:80px;
background-color: #000;
min-height: 140px;
}


.footer-top:before{background-color: #262a2f; position:absolute; top:-50px; 
left:0px; content:""; width:100%;
min-height: 80px;
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Safari */
transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Standard syntax */}


.footer-top { position:relative; margin-top:80px;
background-color: #262a2f;
min-height: 140px;
}
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gth6y1ss/1/

Basically you are not skewing the div, but elements that you put before or after.

There are two solutions for your problem :

1) Just add an element after footer-top (this is what I did, skew it the same way and just translate it a bit in the bottom)

```
.footer-top:after{
background-color: #262a2f; position:absolute; 
top:95px; 
left:0px; content:""; width:100%;
min-height: 80px;
-ms-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Safari */
transform: skew(0deg,2deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

2) Just skew the footer top itself and don't add a footer-top: before at all

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `margin-top` in `.footer-bottom` class form your style.

You can add `padding-top` if you want. See if this solves your problem.